# Unresponsive threading involving Swing and AWT-EventQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, deadlock

I have an application that is unresponsive and seems to be in a deadlock or something like a deadlock.  See the two threads below.  Notice that the `My-Thread@101c` thread blocks `AWT-EventQueue-0@301`.  However, `My-Thread` has just called `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait()`.  So `AWT-EventQueue-0` blocks `My-Thread` (I believe).

```
My-Thread@101c, priority=5, in group 'main', status: 'WAIT'
     blocks AWT-EventQueue-0@301
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source:-1)
      at com.acme.ui.ViewBuilder.renderOnEDT(ViewBuilder.java:157)
        .
        .
        .
      at com.acme.util.Job.run(Job.java:425)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source:-1)

AWT-EventQueue-0@301, priority=6, in group 'main', status: 'MONITOR'
     waiting for My-Thread@101c
      at com.acme.persistence.TransactionalSystemImpl.executeImpl(TransactionalSystemImpl.java:134)
        .
        .
        .
      at com.acme.ui.components.MyTextAreaComponent$MyDocumentListener.insertUpdate(MyTextAreaComponent.java:916)
      at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultFilterBypass.replace(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.replace(Unknown Source:-1)
      at com.acme.ui.components.FilteredDocument$InputDocumentFilter.replace(FilteredDocument.java:204)
      at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source:-1)
      at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source:-1)
```

Here is the `TransactionalSystemImpl.executeImpl` method:

```
private synchronized Object executeImpl(Transaction xact, boolean commit) {
    final Object result;

    try {
        if (commit) { // this is line 134
            clock.latch();
            synchronized(pendingEntries) {
                if (xactLatchCount > 0) {
                    pendingEntries.add(xact);
                } else {
                    xactLog.write(new TransactionEntry(xact, clock.time()));
                }
            }
        }

        final TransactionExecutor executor = transactionExecutorFactory.create(
                xact.getClass().getSimpleName()
        );

        if (executor == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create transaction executor for transaction: " + xact.getClass().getName());
        }

        result = executor.execute(xact);

    } finally {
        if (commit) clock.unlatch();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to figure out what's going on without seeing any code. Can you post some?

Comment: I added a little code.  But it's so complicated that I'm not sure it's worth asking the question here.  And coming up with a simpler example is quite difficult.

Comment: Why are you using two nested synchronized blocks? This is asking for trouble from my experience. I mean the whole method synchronizes on it's object instance, while you also synchronize on pendingEntries which seems to be a member variable of that object? Why not just lock the access to that member variable by the same object monitor? This would make your scenario a bit easier, though it probably is not the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for awarding the bounty to my answer! I hope it helps you get this problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be well known among Swing developers of my acquaintance that `invokeAndWait` is problematic, but maybe this isn't as well known as I had thought. I seem to recall having seen stern warnings in the documentation about difficulties in using `invokeAndWait` properly, yet I'm having a hard time finding anything. I cannot find anything in current, official documentation. The only thing I've been able to find is this line from an old version of the [Swing Tutorial from 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20051230094932/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/threads.html): (web archive)

> If you use `invokeAndWait`, make sure that the thread that calls invokeAndWait does not hold any locks that other threads might need while the call is occurring.

Unfortunately this line seems to have disappeared from the current Swing tutorial. Even this is rather an understatement; I'd have preferred that it say something like, "If you use `invokeAndWait`, the thread that calls `invokeAndWait` **must not** hold any locks that other threads might need while the call is occurring." In general it's difficult to know what locks other threads might need during any given time, the safest policy is probably to ensure that the thread calling `invokeAndWait` **doesn't hold any locks at all**.

(This is pretty difficult to do, and it's why I said above that `invokeAndWait` is problematic. I also know that the designers of JavaFX -- essentially a Swing replacement -- defined in the [javafx.application.Platform](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html) class a method called `runLater` which is functionally equivalent to `invokeLater`. But they *deliberately* omitted an equivalent method to `invokeAndWait` because it's very difficult to use properly.)

The reason is fairly straightforward to derive from first principles. Consider a system similar to the one described by the OP, having two threads: MyThread and the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). MyThread takes a lock on object L and then calls `invokeAndWait`. This posts event E1 and waits for it to be processed by the EDT. Suppose that E1's handler needs to lock L. When the EDT processes event E1, it attempts to take the lock on L. This lock is held already by MyThread, which won't relinquish it until the EDT processes E1, but that processing is blocked by MyThread. Thus we have deadlock.

Here's a variation on this scenario. Suppose we ensure that processing E1 doesn't require locking L. Will this be safe? No. The problem can still occur if, just before MyThread calls `invokeAndWait`, an event E0 is posted to the event queue, and E0's handler requires locking on L. As before, MyThread holds the lock on L, so processing of E0 is blocked. E1 is behind E0 in the event queue so processing of E1 is blocked too. Since MyThread is waiting for E1 to be processed, and it's blocked by E0, which in turn is blocked waiting for MyThread to relinquish the lock on L, we have deadlock again.

This sounds fairly similar to what's going on in the OP's application. According to the OP's comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899750/1441122),

> Yes, renderOnEDT is synchronized on something way up in the call stack, the com.acme.persistence.TransactionalSystemImpl.executeImpl method which is synchronized. And renderOnEDT is waiting to enter that same method. So, that is the source of the deadlock it looks like. Now I have to figure out how to fix it.

We don't have a complete picture, but this is probably enough to go on. `renderOnEDT` is being called from MyThread, which is holding a lock on something while it's blocked in `invokeAndWait`. It's waiting for an event to be processed by the EDT, but we can see the EDT is blocked on something held by MyThread. We can't quite tell exactly which object this is, but it kind of doesn't matter -- the EDT is clearly blocked on a lock held by MyThread, and MyThread is clearly waiting for the EDT to process an event: thus, deadlock.

Note also that we can be fairly sure the EDT isn't currently processing the event posted by `invokeAndWait` (analogous to E1 in my scenario above). If it were, the deadlock would occur every time. It seems to occur only sometimes, and according to a comment from the OP on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900011/1441122), when the user is typing quickly. So I'd bet that the event currently being processed by the EDT is a keystroke that happened to be posted to the event queue after MyThread took its lock, but before MyThread called `invokeAndWait` to post E1 to the event queue, thus it's analogous to E0 in my scenario above.

So far, this is probably mostly a recap of the problem, pieced together from other answers and from the OP's comments on those answers. Before we proceed to talking about a solution, here are some assumptions I'm making about the OP's application:

- It's multi-threaded, so various objects must be synchronized to work properly. This includes calls from Swing event handlers, which presumably update some model based on user interaction, and this model is also processed by worker threads such as MyThread. Therefore, they **must** lock such objects properly. Removing synchronization will definitely avoid deadlocks, but other bugs will creep in as the data structures are corrupted by unsynchronized concurrent access.
- The application isn't necessarily performing long-running operations on the EDT. This is a typical problem with GUI apps but it doesn't seem to be happening here. I'm assuming that the application works fine in most cases, where an event processed on the EDT grabs a lock, updates something, then releases the lock. The problem occurs when it can't get the lock because the lock's holder is deadlocked on the EDT.
- Changing `invokeAndWait` to `invokeLater` isn't an option. The OP has said that doing so causes other problems. This isn't surprising, as that change causes execution to occur in a different order, so it will give different results. I'll assume they would be unacceptable.

If we can't remove locks, and we can't change to `invokeLater`, we're left with calling `invokeAndWait` safely. And "safely" means relinquishing locks before calling it. This might be arbitrarily hard to do given the organization of the OP's application, but I think it's the only way to proceed.

Let's look at what MyThread is doing. This is much simplified, as there are probably a bunch of intervening method calls on the stack, but fundamentally it's something like this:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(handler);
    // code block 2
}
```

The problem occurs when some event sneaks in the queue in front of handler, and that event's processing requires locking `someObject`. How can we avoid this problem? You can't relinquish one of Java's built-in monitor locks within a `synchronized` block, so you have to close the block, make your call, and open it again:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
}

SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(handler);

synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 2
}
```

This could be arbitrarily difficult if the lock on `someObject` is taken fairly far up the call stack from the call to `invokeAndWait`, but I think doing this refactoring is unavoidable.

There are other pitfalls, too. If code block 2 depends on some state loaded by code block 1, that state might be out of date by the time code block 2 takes the lock again. This implies that code block 2 must reload any state from the synchronized object. It mustn't make any assumptions based on results from code block 1, since those results might be out of date.

Here's another issue. Suppose the handler being run by `invokeAndWait` requires some state loaded from the shared object, for example,

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(handler(state1, state2));
    // code block 2
}
```

You couldn't just migrate the `invokeAndWait` call out of the synchronized block, since that would require unsynchronized access getting state1 and state2. What you have to do instead is to load this state into local variables while within the lock, then make the call using those locals after releasing the lock. Something like:

```
int localState1;
String localState2;
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
    localState1 = state1;
    localState2 = state2;
}

SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(handler(localState1, localState2));

synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 2
}
```

The technique of making calls after having released locks is called the *open call* technique. See Doug Lea, *Concurrent Programming in Java* (2nd edition), sec 2.4.1.3. There is also a good discussion of this technique in Goetz et. al., *Java Concurrency In Practice*, sec 10.1.4. In fact all of section 10.1 covers deadlock fairly thoroughly; I recommend it highly.

In summary, I believe that using techniques I describe above, or in the books cited, will solve this deadlock problem correctly and safely. However, I am sure that it will require a lot of careful analysis and difficult restructuring as well. I don't see an alternative, though.

(Finally, I should say that while I am an employee of Oracle, this is not in any way an official statement of Oracle.)

---

**UPDATE**

I thought of a couple more potential refactorings that might help solve the problem. Let's reconsider the original schema of the code:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(handler);
    // code block 2
}
```

This executes code block 1, handler, and code block 2 in order. If we were to change the `invokeAndWait` call to `invokeLater`, the handler would be executed after code block 2. One can easily see that would be a problem for the application. Instead, how about we move code block 2 *into* the `invokeAndWait` so that it executes in the right order, but still on the event thread?

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
}

SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable {
    synchronized (someObject) {
        handler();
        // code block 2
    }
});
```

Here's another approach. I don't know exactly what the handler passed to `invokeAndWait` is intended to do. But one reason it might need to be `invokeAndWait` is that it reads some information out of the GUI and then uses this to update the shared state. This has to be on the EDT, since it interacts with GUI objects, and `invokeLater` can't be used since it would occur in the wrong order. This suggests calling `invokeAndWait` *before* doing other processing in order to read information out of the GUI into a temporary area, then use this temporary area to perform continued processing:

```
TempState tempState;
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable() {
    synchronized (someObject) {
        handler();
        tempState.update();
    }
);

synchronized (someObject) {
    // code block 1
    // instead of invokeAndWait, use tempState from above
    // code block 2
}
```

Comment: `it's why I said above that invokeAndWait is problematic.`- sorry but i see it as a little out of description. This is not that it is problematic, it is designed to do certain job, so simply don't use it for any other job and by no way it makes invokeAndWait problematic

Comment: Sure, `invokeAndWait` doesn't have any bugs, and it does exactly what it's specified to do. It also has the precondition that certain locks mustn't be held when it's called. Your statement "simply don't use it for any other job" includes satisfying this precondition. In practice, it's difficult to know when one is violating this precondition, as the OP's problem illustrates. `invokeLater` has no such restrictions and doesn't risk deadlock. Thus, compared to `invokeLater`, `invokeAndWait` is problematic.

Answer (score 10):

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

**`Event Dispatch Thread and EventQueue`**

Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT). Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are not *thread safe*. All GUI related task, any update should be made to GUI while painting process must happen on the EDT, *which involves wrapping the request in an event and processing it onto the **`EventQueue`***. Then the event are dispatched from the same queue in the one by one in order they en-queued, FIRST IN FIRST OUT. That is, if `Event A` is enqueued to the [`EventQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) before `Event B` then event `B` will not be dispatched before event `A`.

**`SwingUtilities`** class has two useful function to help with GUI rendering task:

- `invokeLater(Runnable)`: Causes `doRun.run()` to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread(EDT). This will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed, as is described above.
- `invokeAndWait(Runnable)`: It has the same function as the `invokeLater` but it differs from `invokeLater` for the fact that:

  1. `invokeAndWait` waits for the task given by it to the EDT, to finish before returning.
  2. it blocks(awaits) the current(i.e., it's invoking thread from continuing it's execution by sending to `WAIT` state by means of synchronizing a lock.
  3. It will release the lock once the event request posted by this function gets dispatched in the EDT and the invoker thread of this function can continue.

The source code has the evidence:

```
  public static void invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable)
    throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {

     if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) 
          throw new Error("Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread");

     class AWTInvocationLock {}
     Object lock = new AWTInvocationLock();

     InvocationEvent event = new InvocationEvent(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(), 
                                                 runnable, lock,
                                                 true);

     synchronized (lock) {  //<<---- locking
           Toolkit.getEventQueue().postEvent(event);
           while (!event.isDispatched()) { //<---- checking if the event is dispatched
                  lock.wait(); //<---- if not tell the current invoking thread to wait 
              }
            }

      Throwable eventThrowable = event.getThrowable();
      if (eventThrowable != null) {
          throw new InvocationTargetException(eventThrowable);
      }
  }
```

This explains the issue:

> My-Thread has just called java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(). So
>   AWT-EventQueue-0 blocks My-Thread (I believe).

**To explain a scenario of deadlock which you are likely having, lets look into an example:**

```
class ExampleClass 
{

    public synchronized void renderInEDT(final Thread t)
    {
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Executinf invokeWait's Runnable ");
                        System.out.println("invokeWait invoking Thread's state: "+t.getState());

                        doOtherJob();
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SwingUtilitiesTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SwingUtilitiesTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

    }

    public synchronized void renderInEDT2(final Thread t)
    {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Executing invokeLater's Runnable ");
                        System.out.println("invokeLater's invoking Thread's state: "+t.getState());
                        doOtherJob();
                    }
                });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExampleClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public synchronized void doOtherJob()
    {
        System.out.println("Executing a job inside EDT");
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have declared three *synchronized* function:

1. `renderInEDT(final Thread t)`:  to execute a Runnable task in the EDT by`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`
2. `renderInEDT2(final Thread t)`: to execute a Runnable task in the EDT by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`
3. `doOtherJob()` : This function is invoked by each of the above two function's `Runnable`'S `run()` method.

The reference of the invoking thread is passed to check the state for each of the invocation of `SwingUtilities` function. Now, if we invoke `renderInEDT()` on an instance `exmpleClass` of `ExampleClass`: Here `Thread t` is declared in the class context:

```
    t =  new Thread("TestThread"){
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    exmpleClass.renderInEDT(t);
                 }

    };
    t.start();
```

The output will be:

```
Executing invokeWait's Runnable 
invokeWait invoking Thread's state: WAITING
```

The `doOtherJob()` method never gets executed in the  EDT posted by `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` because a deadlock situation appears. As the `renderInEDT()` is synchronized and being executed inside a thread namely `t`, the EDT will need to wait to execute `doOtherJob()` until first invoking thread is done executing the `renderInEDT(final Thread t)` method, as is described in the [**`official tutorial source of synchronized method`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> *it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on
>   the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a
>   synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke
>   synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution)
>   until the first thread is done with the object.*

Hence, EDT is waiting for the `t` thread to finish(and suspend) execution, but  thread `t` is actually blocked and sent to waiting state by the  `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` method as described above, hence it is not being able to finish it's execution: *Bth of the EDT and the `t` thread is waiting for each other to be done with their execution*.

Let us see the above example with case: if we post event task using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` as it will be evident if we execute the `renderInEDT2()` function on the `exampleClass` instance from a thread:

```
  t =  new Thread("TestThread"){
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    exmpleClass.renderInEDT2(t);
                 }   
    };
  t.start();
```

This time you will see that, the function invocation continues normally producing following output:

```
Executing invokeLater's Runnable 
invokeLater's invoking Thread's state: TIMED_WAITING
Executing a job inside EDT
```

This time `doOtherJob()` gets executed  by the EDT as soon as the first calling thread of `renderInEDT2()` is done executing it: to emphasize i have put the thread to sleep (3s) to inspect the execution timing and hence it shows the state `TIMED_WAITING`.

This is what explains your second issue: As the exception is telling and also mentioned by you in one of your comment:

> enderOnEDT is synchronized on something way up in the call stack, the
>   com.acme.persistence.TransactionalSystemImpl.executeImpl method which
>   is synchronized. And renderOnEDT is waiting to enter that same method.
>   So, that is the source of the deadlock it looks like. Now I have to
>   figure out how to fix it.

**However**,

- `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)` especially used while we want to block or awaits a thread and ask user confirmation if we should continue using `JOptionPane/JDialogue/JFileChooser` etc.
- Otherwise,  to post a GUI rendering task in the `EventQueue`, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`.
- Although, i have await the EDT using `Thread.sleep(time)` for *demonstration purposes*, Please don't do anything such, which might block the EDT for a mentionable amount of time even if it is few, otherwise your Swing will get frozen and will force you to kill it.
- We should not perform any kind of computational work or read/write operation or any other thing that is not related to GUI rendering task inside EDT aka, inside the `Runnable` of the `invokeAndWait` and  `invokeLater` function.

At this point you yourself should be able to figure out and solve your problem because you are not providing enough details to us of your code. I think while posting your GUI rendering task to Event Queue using a  synchronized function like `enderOnEDT` as you have said in your comment, then I don't see any reason for calling another *synchronized* function from it's `Runnable`. Rather put your rendering function in this `Runnable` directly. That is my sole purpose of explaining the Event Queue and EDT mechanism.

**Reference:**

1. [**`The Event Dispatch Thread`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
2. [**`Class EventQueue`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html)
3. [**`Initial Threads`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
4. [**`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun) documentation`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but from the stack trace, it looks like you're firing some sort of transactional code from the event dispatch thread. Does that code then kick off an instance of My-Thread? The EDT could be blocked waiting for My-Thread from within the transactional code, but My-Thread can't finish because it needs the EDT.

If this is the case, you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for your rendering so the EDT finishes the transactional code and then it will render the updates. Or, you can not perform the transactional code from the EDT. For actual work that's not related to rendering, you should use a SwingWorker to avoid doing any heavy processing on the EDT.

Comment: No, the transactional code is not kicking off an instance of My-Thread.  That is already running at the time.

Comment: Ok. Another thing to check. Are you sure the call to ViewBuilder.renderOnEDT is not occurring from the EDT too (since you probably wouldn't want to call invokeAndWait) from the EDT.

Or, is it possible that the call to renderOnEDT is synchronized on something? Then if the EDT tries to synchronize on that same object (in the 2nd stack trace you posted) while My-Thread is in invokeAndWait,  you will have a deadlock.

Comment: ViewBuilder.renderOnEDT is sometimes called on the EDT, but, in that case, we don't use invokeAndWait:

  if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
   container = renderable.render();
  } else {
   try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(renderable);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
   container = renderable.getContainer();
  }

Comment: Yes, renderOnEDT is synchronized on something way up in the call stack, the com.acme.persistence.TransactionalSystemImpl.executeImpl method which is synchronized.  And renderOnEDT is waiting to enter that same method.  So, that is the source of the deadlock it looks like.  Now I have to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Again without knowing the whole code, I can't provide many more details. But in general, you should avoid synchronizing and long running operations on the EDT. So, using invokeLater should help run the operation on the EDT without blocking it. Also as I mentioned, you should look into using SwingWorker and not doing the transactions on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

Some thread (I assume `My-Thread@101c`) is `synchronized` on your TransactionalSystemImpl instance.  The UI thread is trying to enter `executeImpl` but is blocked on the `synchronized` monitor and cannot.  Where else is the TransactionalSystemImpl instance being used (with `synchronized` entry)?  Probably between

```
  at com.acme.ui.ViewBuilder.renderOnEDT(ViewBuilder.java:157)
    .
    .
    .
  at com.acme.util.Job.run(Job.java:425)
```

Comment: I tried invokeLater, but that caused other problems.  Perhaps this code is too complex to be asking this question here.  Coming up with a small test case that reproduces the problem would be really difficult, though.

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening.  The user is quickly typing characters.  So how to fix this?

Comment: I might have to change it to invokeLater() and then fix the resulting problems.

Comment: +1 for brilliant and concise analysis of the problem

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the line 134 you quoted is not the real line 134 (can be caused by stale code, or some other issues).  It seems that 134 is waiting for a monitor, which most probably means `synchronized(pendingEntries)`, (or the `clock.latch()` which I think it is some kind of countdown latch?)

From the stack trace, the AWT event dispatching thread is waiting for a monitor, which is held by MyThread.

Please check the code base on the stack trace of MyThread.  I believe somewhere it sync on `pendingEntries`, then it used `invokeAndWait` to ask the event dispatching thread to do something, and in turn the event dispatching thread is waiting for `pendingEntries`, which caused the deadlock.

---

A suggestion that is a bit off topics:  Your event dispatching thread seems doing a lot more than it should.  I don't think doing those transaction handling etc in the event dispatching thread is a good choice.  Such action can be slow (and in this case, even blocks the event dispatching thread), which will cause UI to be unresponsive.

Splitting such action to a separate thread/executor seems a better choice for me.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other deadlocks running around, you can transform the call to `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)` into a blocking version that waits until your `Runnable` is completed:

```
if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) r.run();
else {
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        r.run();
        try {
            lock.lock();
            locked.set(false);
            condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    });

    try {
        lock.lock();
        while (locked.get())
            condition.await();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

invokeAndWait is not allowed from EDT and should through exception. But looking at stacktrace it looks like because you are using your wrapper thread its allowing you to call invokeAndWait but thats not right. Changing it to SwingUtilities.invokeLater should fix this problem.

Alternate solution: if its worth you can also look into SwingWroker class for worker threads. Here is the link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Just adding some further information about deadlock:
The Javadoc of invokeAndWait clearly mentions "This will happen after all pending events are processed." That includes the current event is calling invokeAndWait. invokeAndWait will wait for the current event to finish, and the current event wait for invokeAndWait to finish. That's a guaranteed deadlock, and that's why it isn't allowed.

Comment: `invokeAndWait` is not being called from the EDT.  It's being called from `My-Thread`.

Comment: If invokeAndWait is called from a "wrapper thread" then it's not being called on the EDT anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell with the little information you give us. Then the code is full of bad coding practice that basically every second line could cause some issues. So all I can do is some sophisticated guesses:

The line 134 does not contain anything that could cause a lock, so the information in the stacktrace has to be off. I assume that commit is true, as otherwise the code would hang on the executor creation, which is sufficiently complex for the JVM to not optimize that out of the stacktrace. Therefore the line where it hangs has to be the `clock.latch()` call. I don't know what it does, but given the try/finally structure it has to be something important, maybe related to threading.

Then the "why does it hang". As you already stated two threads try to access the Swing thread for some work, but at least one never returns, which obviously results in a deadlock of all Swing components. To block the Swing thread someone has to at least call it, but no single line in the code presented does that, so again: sophisticated guessing.

The first synchronized statement cannot be the reason, as it has already been passed, the second is not in the stacktrace but considering that this one might be faulty, it could probably be just in the progress of being called thanks to JVM code re-ordering for optimization.

That leaves two candidates for this issue: the one is the `clock.latch()`, which can cause an issue, but only if it internally does any form of synchronization, for example being declared as `synchronized void latch()`, although I cannot tell how this would block as there is too little information. But based on the code presented, I assume that the rest of the program is in equal bad shape, so that isn't this far off. The second possibility is the `synchronized(pendingEntries)`, but again: there is no evidence in the data presented that could cause this, but given the example anything goes.

Comment: The problem is not about the inner code portion of the function: `synchronized Object executeImpl()` rather the problem is that this function is *`synchronized`* which i have explained. Thank you

Comment: I am not disagreeing with your statement at all, I just try to guess where this synchronized call comes from.